# OrderBy and Distinct from database to Combobox

Tags: c#, linq

I get the data from database and display it in Combobox.

```
public IQueryable<ComboboxKeyAndValue> GetMiejscowosciComboboxItems()
{
    return
        (
            from Obiekty in ATMAEntites.Obiekty
            select new ComboboxKeyAndValue
            {
                Key = Obiekty.idObiektu,
                Value = Obiekty.miejscowosc,
            }
        ).ToList().AsQueryable();
}
```

I would like to show data in Combobox but with sorted alphabetically and without repetition (return only differen values). I did it so, however the code did not work since data in Combobox are neither sorted nor grouped

```
public IQueryable<ComboboxKeyAndValue> GetMiejscowosciComboboxItems()
{
    return
        (
            from Obiekty in ATMAEntites.Obiekty
            orderby Obiekty.miejscowosc
            select new ComboboxKeyAndValue
            {
                Key = Obiekty.idObiektu,
                Value = Obiekty.miejscowosc,
            }
        ).Distinct().ToList().AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: You could create a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<ComboboxKeyAndValue>` and pass an instance of it to the `Distinct` method. This will remove any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The `Distinct()` method will not remove duplicates and you should use `group by` either by keys or values.
for instance you can follow this instruction:

```
var lst = ATMAEntites.Obiekty
      .OrderBy(item=>item.miejscowosc)
      .GroupBy(item => item.idObiektu)
      .Select(group => new 
        { 
             key = group.Key,  
             value = group.ToList() 
       })
      .ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, but it possible do that without using Lambda?